Heat current through a material with variable conductance
Can anyone explain how temperature at any point on the rod (or any material in general) varies with distance when conductivity is variable. This question came to my mind from my physics test last week, I got the following question in it.
A rod of length $l$ and cross-sectional area $A$ has a variable conductivity given by $K = aT$, where $a$ is a positive constant and $T$ is temperature in kelvin. Two ends of the rod are maintained at temperature $T_1$ and $T_2$ $(T_1 > T_2)$. Heat current flowing through the rod will be:
The answer given in the answer key was $$\frac{Aa\left(T_1^2-T_2^2\right)}{2l}$$ I could not solve the question during the test. But now the test is over and I want to find what mistakes I made.So as I was analyzing the question, trying to solve this on my own at home, I spent hours but somehow my answer didn't match with the answer key.
This is my best approach:
My first thought was that as the heat current $I_H$ is going to be constant at any cross section of the rod, by the equation of continuity, as the area of cross section is constant throughout the rod.
So using: (where $R_{total}$ is the total thermal resistance of the rod) $$I_H = \frac{T_1-T_2}{R_{total}}$$
If I can find net thermal resistance of the rod, I can solve the question.
We know that thermal resistance is given by:$$R = \frac{l}{KA}$$
For a small thermal resistance of an element of rod of length $\mathrm dx$ at a distance x from $T_1$ $$\mathrm dR = \frac{\mathrm dx}{\left(aT\right)A}$$
Now we need to find a relation between $T$ and $x$.
By using the concept of temperature gradient, We know that,$$T_1-T = \frac{x}{l}(T_1-T_2)$$
Therefore, $$T = T_1- \frac{x}{l}(T_1-T_2)$$
On put the value of $T$, $$\int_0^R dR = \frac{1}{aA}\int_0^l \frac{1}{T_1-\frac{x}{l}(T_1-T_2)} dx$$
On simplification, $$R = \frac{l}{aA(T_1-T_2)} ln\left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)$$
On put $R$ in the equation $1$, $$I_H = \frac{aA(T_1-T_2)^2}{l \times ln\left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)}$$
So this was my answer, but as you know my answer is somehow wrong according of the answer key. Although I have now understood that the mistake in my solution was that temperature gradient is not constant throughout the rod. But still, I don't the concept about how can we find temperature at any point on the rod (or any material in general)

Consider learning calculus. It is needed to solve cases where gradient is not constant, such as this one.

I'll deduce some relation between heat current and Temperature gradient, but if you don't have any background in vectorial calculus, you can skip this deduction and go to the part where I apply the formula.
Relation between current and Temperature gradient for axial symmetric system
The Fourier law says that
$$
\mathbf q = -k\nabla T
$$
where $\mathbf q$ is the heat flux density and $k$ is conductivity. To calculate the total heat current, we should consider
$$
I_H = \int_S \mathbf q \cdot d\mathbf S = -\int_S k \nabla T \cdot d\mathbf S
$$
As you said, we have axial symmetry. Let $d\mathbf S = \hat{n}dS$ where $\hat{n}$ be the unit vector parallel to the rod. Everything on the right hand side is independent on the transverse variables, so
$$
I_H = - k \nabla T\cdot \hat{n}\oint_S d\mathbf S = -k{dT\over dl} A
$$
Where I denoted $\nabla T \cdot \hat n $ as the directional derivative ${dT\over d l}$.
Finding the heat current
We need to apply the formula
$$
I_H = -AK(T){dT\over dl}.
$$
If we integrate in the length $l$ both sides, we have
$$
I_H \int_0^l dl = - \int_0^l AK(T){dT\over dl} dl = -A\int_{T_1}^{T_2} K(T) dT
$$
On the left hand side I used the fact that the current is the same along the rod. Now we just use the fact that $K=aT$
$$
I_H l = -aA \int_{T_1}^{T_2} T dT = -{aA(T_1^2-T_2^2)\over 2}
$$
The minus sign is due to the fact that the current flows in opposite direction of the gradient, since the gradient points to the maximum of temperature and heat current flows from the maximum to the minimum of temperature.

I don't know your background in calculus, but to solve it without any background in calculus, it should be considered some of the formulas that I deduced here.
